# Float and display block not working on Android 4.4 Native Email

Tags: email, html-email

I have a table with 2 columns and I have put display:block or float: left on the td. I want to wrap TD to full width on mobile. but It appears display:block and float left doesn't work on Android 4.4 Native Email. Android 4.2 Native Email is working very well.

Is anyone having problems with media queries after updating to Kit Kat? display:block doesn't seem to be working anymore?

If anyone has any tips on sorting this out, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"/>

    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-device-width:740px) {
            td[class="float"] { display:block !important;float: left !important; width: 100% !important;} 
            td[class="float-red"] { display:block !important;float: left !important; width: 100% !important;background-color:yellow !important; }
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="backgroundTable" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="outer">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" align="center">
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" class="inner">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="300" bgcolor="red" class="float-red">Testing  Testing</td>
                                <td width="300" bgcolor="blue" class="float">Testing  Testing</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the update, Android no longer supports the TD responsive design technique (see here for more info - https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/how_android_is_strangling_responsive_design).

From there you have a couple options to solve this.

1.) Switch from TDs to the table layout with "align". (See option 2 in the following - http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/responsive-email/responsive-column-layouts/)  This can cause some issues with alignment and spacing between tables (e.g. Outlook likes adding a 10px gutter between nested tables), etc.  There are conditional codes and such that can help to solve these issues, it mostly just takes practice and lots of testing.

2.) Change your TDs into THs.  Although it no longer supports responsive TDs, it DOES support responsive THs. (see here for more info - http://labs.actionrocket.co/td-or-not-to-td-that-is-now-a-question) There are some things that need to be considered when swithcing to TH. For instance by default TH usually has font-weight: bold and aligns center. You also will want to wrap your content inside the TH in a table for better control. Adding padding and margins, etc to a TH can have a much different effect than adding it to a TD.

There is no real perfect solution, but if you have already built a template based on TD responsive design, the easiest transition should be to change to TH.  I would read the action rocket article and do some testing, but should be fairly easy.

Comment: Wow, the TH trick is amazing. Using align isn't really worth the effort and comes with its own set of issues IMO. Stacking is much quicker when coding and it's easier to maintain. I can definitely deal with the difference in default styles... Thanks!